# How can I get an image from LMDB in Python?

Tags: python, image, lmdb

How can I get an image from LMDB in Python?

And what is the data type of that result? Would that data type match the function `open('xx.jpg').read()`?

My purpose is to read an image from LMDB, and then match my code (that code is written for the data type of `open('xx.jpg').read()`), so I want to get the same data type from LMDB if I can.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the layout of the IMDB page you wish to get this image from.
If it is simply a pure jpg url, you can do this:

```
import urllib
import image

urllib.urlretrieve("http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg2NDE5NDEyNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTA3MzgwNjE@._V1_UX100_CR0,0,100,100_AL_.jpg", "moviePoster.jpg")

jpgfile = image.open("moviePoster.jpg")
```

If the url doesn't lead to a single jpg file, you might want to look into using a library like [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), in order to search for the images first

Comment: LMDB and IMDB are not the same thing